# Query large DataSet .NET Core for serialization

Tags: sql, json, serialization, .net-core

I have a fairly large SQL DB (~7GB) with many tables. Looping through these tables with an automated SELECT query results in various size DataSets - some are smaller while others tend to grow huge. Although small sets give no issue, large ones slow down the process and it never finishes (or maybe it would it a few days, I haven't actually tried that for obvious reasons).

All data is to be serialized (using Newtonsoft JSON here).

Code is simple:

```
 private void GetConnection(string connectionString, string statement)
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(statement, connectionString);
        da.Fill(ds);
        SerializeDataSet(ds);
    }
```

Please note that:

- This is a .NET Core Console app
- I have no right to make changes in the DB
  (such as breaking down big tables to smaller ones. It is what it is.)
- Tricks, that can work when an app is created for users (such as lazy
  loading of the data, pagination) won't work here as I'm serializing
  the data to JSON so I need to retrieve all the data at once.

Looking for a useful solution should you have one, thank you.

Comment: Converting 7GB data to a JSON string will *always* be slow and result in files that are several times larger than the original. Using *datasets* for this will multiply the required RAM and time.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why convert a *database* into JSON strings in the first place? That's a very .... unusual requirement to say the least. In any case, what you ask is an ETL question and Datasets and adapters aren't meant for such jobs. Use a SqlCommand and ExecuteReader to read rows as fast as possible.